# Markov Chain Monte Carlo Simulation Prooblem

Tags: python, montecarlo, markov-chains, stochastic-process

I'm trying to run a MC simulator for a Markov Chain that is uniformly distributed among all NxN matrices that have no neighboring 1's. My algo is supposed to fill up the state space by running the chain a bunch of times. However there's something horribly wrong with my logic somewhere and the state space just isn't filling up. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my code.

```
import random
import numpy

M=numpy.zeros((52,52),dtype=int)
z=0
State_Space=[]

for i in range(1,100):
    x=random.randint(1,50)
    y=random.randint(1,50)

    T=M
    if T[x][y]==1:
        T[x][y]=0
    if T[x][y]==0:
        T[x][y]=1


    if T not in State_Space:
    if T[x+1][y+1]==0 and T[x+1][y-1]==0 and T[x-1][y-1]==0 and T[x-1][y+1]==0:
        State_Space.append(T)
        M=T


    else:
         if T[x+1][y+1]==0 and T[x+1][y-1]==0 and T[x-1][y-1]==0 and T[x-1][y+1]==0:
            M=T
    print State_Space
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice two things:

First in line 12 you have `T=M` and I assume you want `T=M.copy()`. Doing `T=M` makes T and M reference the same matrix, so changing a value in T will affect M also. If you assign a copy of M to T then this won't happen.

Second, `T not in State_Space` is not checking for T in the State_Space array. Because of how numpy indexing works, the in operator cannot be used for arrays. If you tried `T in State_Space` with a non-empty State_Space you would get a ValueError about truth value ambiguity. Instead you need to check if any element of State_Space is equal to T. We should use `if any(numpy.array_equal(T, X) for X in State_Space):`

In the end, my code looks like this:

```
import random
import numpy

M=numpy.zeros((52,52),dtype=int)
z=0
State_Space=[]

for i in range(1,100):
    x=random.randint(1,50)
    y=random.randint(1,50)

    T=M.copy()
    if T[x][y]==1:
        T[x][y]=0
    if T[x][y]==0:
        T[x][y]=1

    if not any(numpy.array_equal(T, X) for X in State_Space):
        if T[x+1][y+1]==0 and T[x+1][y-1]==0 and T[x-1][y-1]==0 and T[x-1][y+1]==0:
            State_Space.append(T)
            M=T
    else:
        if T[x+1][y+1]==0 and T[x+1][y-1]==0 and T[x-1][y-1]==0 and T[x-1][y+1]==0:
            M=T
    print len(State_Space)
```

After running, I have ~90 entries in State_Space.

Comment: Brilliant! Ok I am going to run this in my ide. Btw I am using Python 2.7, will that effect anything?

Comment: @kalharrt I may also ask you one more question about this code if that is alright.

Comment: I just edited the code, the only difference was removing parenthesis around the print statement. Questions are welcomed :)

Comment: do you have time to answer one more question?

Comment: @EhBabay sure, just ask

Comment: please look at my post below this.